# Moving a snake in snake game with SFML C++

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying  to make a snake game with SFML+CPP. For now i want to focus on collision, so when a snake goes to the left it needs to come back on the right side of the screen. With some help of the similar questions i have succeeded to make the snake move partially correct to the left and upper side (x and y coordinates)(partially because when going left it jumps like 20px coming out of right side). Here's the code that works like described,the main problem is the right and lower parts.

```
void Game::update()
{
    sf::Vector2f movement(0.0f, 0.0f);
    if (movingUp) { movement.y -= 0.1f;    }
    if (movingDown) { movement.y += 0.1f;  }
    if (movingLeft) { movement.x -= 0.1f;  }
    if (movingRight) { movement.x += 0.1f; }

    for(auto& snakey : snake){
        if (snakey.getPosition().x <= 0 ) { movement.x = myWindow.getSize().y; }
        if (snakey.getPosition().y <= 0 ) { movement.y = myWindow.getSize().x; }
        if (snakey.getPosition().x + snakey.getLocalBounds().width >= myWindow.getSize().x )  { movement.y = 0.0f;}
        if (snakey.getPosition().y + snakey.getLocalBounds().height >= myWindow.getSize().y ) { movement.x = 0.0f;}
        snakey.move(movement);
    } /*If the whole background would be a map of vectors i could technically push the snake vector from head to tail (stack) onto the beginning?*/
}
```

Thanks in advance.
**Edit**
It seems like i missed to ask the question directly so here it is. How do i move the snake as intended(go to the left, come out of the right etc)?

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: How to achieve moving the snake as it should?

Comment: Umm... That was a rhetorical question. What you want is for us to write your code for you. Probably not gonna happen. You need to ask your question in such a way that we can answer it without having to write any (or as little as posible) code.

Comment: But basically, I think there is a problem in the way you change the snake's position. Remember that your sprite (or whatever sfml shape you're using) has it's origin in the top left corner of the shape. So when you change it's position, you need to take into account the size of the shape. Example : When the snake goes too far on the left, you need to set it's X position to ```window_width - snake_width - 1``` (You can remove the ```-1``` if you check for collision using ```<``` instead of ```<=```)

Comment: I mean, if there isn't any way to explain what i need to do then even writing a code for me would help. That way i wouldn't be stuck forever on something, and i would know what to do when/if i encounter similiar problem in future. But if we can avoid that, i am fine with trying myself.

Comment: Okay, i will try to make better questions next time. But isn't what u wrote supposed to just abide me from going to left, and not actually make make my snake come out of the right part of the window?

Comment: I explained to you how to set the position of your snake after it has collided with the left side.

Comment: I noticed my left and/or upper(x,y) parts of the windows are heavily dependent on what i set in my right and/or lower(height, width) parts of the window. Why is that so?

Comment: Actually, i just checked and it was because i mixed the ```x``` and ```y``` coordinates. Also, i have figured what to do, and it works. Should i add a self-answer?